# Application always stopping after adding webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com"); to "OnClickListener"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Currently I am working on a project(It' a browser). There are 2  layout files one is `activity_main.xml` and other is `url_load_activity.xml`. In activity main file there are 10 image views with `android:clickable="true"` and they are with `OnClickListeners`in the MainActivity.java. The other XML contains a `WebView` and a `LinearLayout` for search bar, home button. I added

```
Intent yt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, url_load_activity.class);
startActivity(yt);
```

these 2 lines to each `OnClickListener` of the image views in `MainActivity.java` for switching to `url_load_activity.xml` from `activity_main.xml`. It successfully switched for `url_load_activity.xml`. And then I need to load a URL in the `url_load_activity.xml` while switching to it but when clicked on that image view with `webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");`, the application stops and restarts. In the android studio there shows this error

```
2021-08-30 14:34:58.781 27973-27973/com.blurredtechnology.browser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blurredtechnology.browser, PID: 27973
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.blurredtechnology.browser.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7171)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7148)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27409)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7642)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Other image views are working well without the `webView.loadUrl("");` but after adding `webView.loadUrl("")`to each the error shows always

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) Your `webView` isn't initialised (have you called `findViewById` in `onCreate`?), it is `null`, and you are trying to call some method on it (`loadUrl`) - this is a `NullPointerException` which you are facing

Comment: Please share the code where you are loading the web view.

Comment: @snachmsm, Yes I initialised WebView in `onCreate` but the WebView isn't in the `Main_Activity.xml` it's in `url_load_activity.xml` and I initialised WebView in `MainActivity.java` not in `url_load_activity.java`.

Comment: without code of these Activities its hard to guess whats wrong in your code...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't give empty string to "webview.loadUrl("Here is should filled with string");".

**WebView just trying to open url but when try its exploding because empty string meant nothing to loadUrl function.**

*You should check string before load or don't give empty string to loadUrl function.*